# Computing the Fourier series of $f(\theta)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi\alpha}e^{i(\pi-\theta)\alpha}$ for $x\in[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series, integration-by-parts

Just like the previous question I asked, this one has a solution on p. 36 of Stein and Shakarchi's *Fourier Analysis*: $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{in\theta}}{n+\alpha}$.

But when I tried computing the Fourier coefficients I got $\hat{f}(n)=\frac{e^{i\pi\alpha}\sin(\pi(\pi+n))}{(\pi+n)\sin\pi\alpha}$, so the Fourier series would be $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(n)=\frac{e^{i\pi\alpha}\sin(\pi(\pi+n))}{(\pi+n)\sin\pi\alpha}e^{in\theta}$ . . .

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you show your work leading to what you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Recall:** We have
>   $$
> \frac{e^{i\pi\alpha}-e^{-i\pi\alpha}}{2i}=\sin(\pi\alpha)
> $$

Now it's just a matter of computation:
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(n) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi­\alpha)}e^{i(\pi-t)\alpha}e^{-int}\,dt \\
&=\frac{1}{\sin(\pi­\alpha)}\cdot\frac{e^{i\pi\alpha}}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it(n+\alpha)}\,dt \\
&=\frac{1}{\sin(\pi­\alpha)}\cdot\frac{e^{i\pi\alpha}}{2}\cdot\bigg(\frac{1-e^{-2i\pi(n+\alpha)}}{i(n+\alpha)}\bigg) \\
&=\frac{1}{\sin(\pi­\alpha)}\cdot\frac{e^{i\pi\alpha}(1-e^{-2i\pi\alpha})}{2i}\cdot\frac{1}{n+\alpha} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sin(\pi­\alpha)}\cdot\frac{e^{i\pi\alpha}-e^{-i\pi\alpha}}{2i}\cdot\frac{1}{n+\alpha}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin(\pi­\alpha)}\cdot\sin(\pi\alpha)\cdot\frac{1}{n+\alpha}\\
&=\frac{1}{n+\alpha}
\end{align}
By the way it is assumed that $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ otherwise $f$ would not make sense.